# MS Excel - How to add percentage increase to the forecast chart and/or pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I've managed to successfully create a Forecast line chart. It has produced a table including forecast values, which is great. However, I'd really like to know what % increase it's working on? How would I go about adding this column to the Forecast table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to follow these steps:**

1. Using Source Data find Forecast in `Col C.`

[image]

1. Plot the Line Chart.
2. Find the difference in Cell `Col D` by using this Formula in cell `D103`, apply **Percentage** cell format.

   `=IF(B103="","",(C108-B103)/B103)`.
3. Write click Plot Area & click **Select Data**.
4. This time add Range `D103:D108` and name it to *Difference.*

[image]

5. Select the **Difference Series** and apply **Cell Value** as **Data Label**.
6. Finally add **Secondary Axis** to the Chart.

*You find this:*

[image]

*Adjust Cell references as needed.*

Comment: This is amazing, Raj. Thank you! Just one question, the second data label shows a 381% increase. Is there a reason why you used C108 to work out this value? For some reason I thought that the second Difference data label would be based on the % increase from B:103 to B:104?

Comment: Glad to help you @sonic99 ,,, these are sample data, genuine data set make lots of difference, I've used July 07th onwards for Forecast which can be re-design as your need,,, if you wish you may accept it as Answer as well up vote also ☺